# xHTMLImporter.convert(String, null) null pointer exception

Tags: html, docx4j

I don t understand why I get a null pointer exception sometimes when trying to convert HTML to docx.

I use docx4j 3.2.1 with all dependencies and this is the code

```
private void ajoutDescription(String description, int maxWidth) {
        if (description != null) {
            if (description.length() > 1) {
                description = formattageDescription(description, maxWidth);
                try {
                    xHTMLImporter = new XHTMLImporterImpl(wordMLPackage);
                    wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().addAll(xHTMLImporter.convert(description, null));
                } catch (Docx4JException e) {
                    System.out.println("bug ajout desc");
                    System.out.println(description);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    System.out.println("bug ajout desc not Docx4j");
                    System.out.println(description);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is the error and the description arg in xHTMLImporter.convert(description, null)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1" />
  <style type="text/css">p, ul, li, table, tr, td, font{font-family: Arial;font-size:120%}img{max-width:902px; height:auto;}</style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p><img id="img1983" src="file:///C:/Users/david.guy/.caliberrm/4FA4F864-5D3E-4A30-A684-163FADFEB4D9.PNG" /></p>
 </body>
</html>
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.docx4j.finders.RangeFinder.apply(RangeFinder.java:59)
    at org.docx4j.finders.RangeFinder.walkJAXBElements(RangeFinder.java:106)
    at org.docx4j.finders.RangeFinder.walkJAXBElements(RangeFinder.java:109)
    at org.docx4j.finders.RangeFinder.walkJAXBElements(RangeFinder.java:109)
    at org.docx4j.finders.RangeFinder.walkJAXBElements(RangeFinder.java:109)
    at org.docx4j.finders.RangeFinder.walkJAXBElements(RangeFinder.java:109)
    at org.docx4j.finders.RangeFinder.walkJAXBElements(RangeFinder.java:109)
    at org.docx4j.TraversalUtil.<init>(TraversalUtil.java:209)
    at org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml.BookmarkHelper.initBookmarkIdStart(BookmarkHelper.java:92)
    at org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml.BookmarkHelper.getBookmarkId(BookmarkHelper.java:82)
    at org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml.BookmarkHelper.anchorToBookmark(BookmarkHelper.java:187)
    at org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml.XHTMLImporterImpl.traverse(XHTMLImporterImpl.java:834)
    at org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml.XHTMLImporterImpl.traverse(XHTMLImporterImpl.java:1236)
    at org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml.XHTMLImporterImpl.traverse(XHTMLImporterImpl.java:1216)
    at org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml.XHTMLImporterImpl.traverse(XHTMLImporterImpl.java:1216)
    at org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml.XHTMLImporterImpl.traverse(XHTMLImporterImpl.java:796)
    at org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml.XHTMLImporterImpl.convert(XHTMLImporterImpl.java:680)
    at com.simat.export.docx.ModuleToDocxSFDGenerator.ajoutDescription(ModuleToDocxSFDGenerator.java:1683)
    at com.simat.export.docx.ModuleToDocxSFDGenerator.ajoutMaquettes(ModuleToDocxSFDGenerator.java:788)
    at com.simat.export.docx.ModuleToDocxSFDGenerator.ecritureCURecursive(ModuleToDocxSFDGenerator.java:434)
    at com.simat.export.docx.ModuleToDocxSFDGenerator.ecritureCURecursive(ModuleToDocxSFDGenerator.java:377)
    at com.simat.export.docx.ModuleToDocxSFDGenerator.ecritureCU(ModuleToDocxSFDGenerator.java:345)
    at com.simat.export.docx.ModuleToDocxSFDGenerator.lancerExportDocx(ModuleToDocxSFDGenerator.java:196)
    at com.simat.export.docx.ModuleToDocxSFDGenerator.docxParser(ModuleToDocxSFDGenerator.java:176)
    at com.simat.test.TestSFD.main(TestSFD.java:109)
```

I have no idea how to fix this. Some images do not cause this bug but i don t know which ones do.

Comment: fixed by removing id attribute from img tag

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.docx4j.finders.RangeFinder.apply(RangeFinder.java:59)
at org.docx4j.finders.RangeFinder.walkJAXBElements(RangeFinder.java:106)
:
at org.docx4j.finders.RangeFinder.walkJAXBElements(RangeFinder.java:109)
at org.docx4j.TraversalUtil.<init>(TraversalUtil.java:209)
at org.docx4j.convert.in.xhtml.BookmarkHelper.initBookmarkIdStart(BookmarkHelper.java:92)
```

By removing @id, you avoided the error, since anchorToBookmark is no longer invoked.

This issue looks like it is triggered by the contents of your wordMLPackage, so if it happens again, please post your docx.

Comment: docx is not generated in this case as the run is interrupted. But I can generate the error again and continue through this Exception so the application can finish its run and generate the docx if you are interested.